# How can I remove an answer ban, if I agree with why one was deleted?

Tags: discussion, post-ban

I recently found I have an answer ban, after finding a couple of my posts were deleted.

The documentation recommends that users in my situation edit their posts to be correct, so that this ban be lifted, but the issue is I think the moderators were correct in deleting my post (as I only posted a link without further info, and I added a new answer with this info). I now know that this is not good practice in answers, but that doesn't help me for a historic post.

I think Stack Overflow users should given chance to learn from their mistakes, and having answers deleted is a good way of finding out your answers were poor, but an answer ban makes it impossible to post good answers and redeem yourself.

I would suggest a button like "I acknowledge this answer was not helpful and retract my answer" would be useful.

Also according to this post there is a secret really easy way to lift an answer ban, but this doesn't help me: [Does an answer ban allow you to post an answer once every 6 months? Can we make this more clear?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/347809/does-an-answer-ban-allow-you-to-post-an-answer-once-every-6-months-can-we-make/347812#347812)

Comment: That you agree with the ban is irrelevant; the way to remove the ban is to improve the quality of your content. A moderator, *cannot* remove the ban, not even a CM can. The entire thing is determined by an (undisclosed) algorithm.

Comment: If you have improved the answers, and they were moderator deleted (not curator deleted), then you can then raise a custom moderator flag on that post for undeletion and explain you've improved the post to address the moderator deletion reason. If the answer has been adequately improved, it may well gain some upvotes (or have users remove their downvotes). That, however, is often a slow process.

Comment: As soon as you prove that you can contribute positively, the answer ban will go away. It's one of the easiest to get out of.

Comment: If you agree with the reasoning of why the content was removed though, in some situations it just can't be improved.  I see that this is the outcome of the stack overflow algorithm, but the system has created a sort of catch-22, where users with poor ratings can't improve them if they have nothing to add to their original posts.

Comment: If you don't think any of your prior answers can be improved then you're not really showing us that you can contribute positively scoring answers. None of them are positively scored, you don't think you can improve any so surely both you and we should conclude that any future answers would go the same way. If so, why should you contribute answers and why should we let you?

Comment: So none of my answers have been downvoted except the 2 that were deleted. These 2 I posted at the same time, to supply a URL for users who might be looking for an answer to two separate questions (the URL did have the solution at the time of posting, I just wasn't aware of the rule about URLs).

Comment: I see of your four undeleted answers, you've answered the same question twice (You have 2 answers each on 2 questions), why this particular repetition?

Comment: Sure, so I came up with a couple of different solutions to the same problem as I thought more about it. The second one I thought was better than the first, so I thought it would be useful to add

Comment: If you feel that you can't improve any of your deleted / non-deleted answers, try to contribute in other ways, editing, (useful) questions, maybe flagging / closing, etc where appropriate.

Comment: "I acknowledge" Everyone would claim they agree their posts were bad. The only way to make sure that people can post good content after bad is demonstrating that they know what good content is. [(Yes, it's possible.)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/347809/does-an-answer-ban-allow-you-to-post-an-answer-once-every-6-months-can-we-make/347812#comment1265605_347812).

Comment: Not downvoted <> good post.

Comment: I remember when I started (answering) on 'SO', I had a "pool" of 5 (Max) Answers I could use, you possibly only 4 if 1 got deleted by a Mod, and I would regularly delete some older Answer to be able to post a new one, as I was sometimes (mis)using the Answer field as a (Temp) Comment asking for clarification, as I was <50-Rep. You've posted twice 2 separate Answers on 2 of your Qt's (Questions), => incorporate those 2 Answers each time in one single one per Question, and you'll have 2 Answers left from your "pool of 4"... :idea:

Comment: @chivracq deleting questions / answers does not help one get out of a question / answer ban.

Comment: @Abdul, I don't know anything about Questions, (never asked any), I just describe how it worked for me, with only Answers, until "one day" I was able to post a 6th Answer, and so on...

Comment: @chivracq it's true though that this is good advice for new users, if I were doing it again I think I would modify my existing answer rather than posting new ones. Also I agree re comments - the fact you can't comment till 50 rep encourages new users to use answers in place of comments, which is definitely bad practice.

Comment: @chivracq advicing people to delete their posts is just going to make the question / answer ban more difficult for them, please don't do so.

Comment: *"and having answers deleted is a good way of finding out your answers were poor"* - no seeing them downvoted does that.

Comment: 'I would suggest a button like "I acknowledge this answer was not helpful and retract my answer" would be useful.' This would make the ban pretty useless. While it's debatable whether it's good to allow *no one* to lift the ban, allowing *the offender* to lift the ban themselves effectively makes all repercussions void.

Comment: In my experience very few users believe their low quality answer is actually low quality. So even if there was an option to retract their own answer very few authors would use it.

Comment: *"So I recently found I have an answer ban*" According to our information, you don't currently have an answer ban, and you never have.  Could you clarify what makes you think you do? (please reply with @RyanM)

Comment: I note that you don't have the informed badge. [Take the tour and earn it](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). You'll find that it's easier to garner support for "I screwed up because I didn't know what I was doing!" posts when it's clear you read at least some of the site documentation.

Answer (score 4):

An example of the problem is one of your questions (not linking here to avoid the Meta Effect).

You posted 3 answers to your own question. Just edit and update one if you have things to add; Stack Overflow is not a forum to start multiple subthreads.

To highlight the problem, you have 3 not well-received answers: 2 with a 0 score and 1 with a score of -3 (the link only).

The proper course of action according to the timeline would have been to Edit your first answer to add the link about the proper solution (I'm keeping it in line with your knowledge at that time). After a comment was left about it being a link-only answer you should have done what you did in your last answer; explain how to solve the problem and provide a link to your source.

Your best bet now is to contribute positively on your question and trying to improve your existing answers. Do your best to make them right to get some upvotes on it. If you achieve that the ban will be lifted.

Comment: In this case I believe they already got out of the answer ban, they posted one answer after posting this current question (They got an upvote on one of their answers).

Comment: “Your best bet now is to wait a bit until you are allowed to post answers again” - Answer bans don’t work like that. The author can wait until the end of time, but unless they receive legitimate upvotes on the answer they already have their answer ban won’t be lifted unfortunately in this case they have duplicate answers so there is no fixing those duplicates.

Comment: @SecurityHound You are correct that answer bans specifically don't allow you to post any answers until you get out of the ban (see [staff confirmation here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/347809/323179)). However, pretty much any positive contribution to the site will easily lift an answer ban. For example, a question that's positively received (even a little!) will be a big help to getting out of an answer ban.

Comment: Edited to give a better advice then ;)